# Using a single certificate for inter-node encryption on Cassandra

Tags: ssl, encryption, cassandra

I have inter-node encryption setup on a small Cassandra cluster (4 nodes), and each node has its own key pair. That means that I need to distribute a trusted keystore to all nodes that contains the public key for every other node in the cluster, which makes it a bit of a pain to update when I add nodes to the cluster.

Does Cassandra allow using a single certificate/key for all nodes in a cluster, or will it complain? All the docs I see online tell me to generate a separate key pair for each node, but does not address sharing certificates. If it is allowed, what are the drawbacks to this method?

Comment: Does cassandra support certificate chains? The idea is to check whether it is possible to create trust store with "certificate authority" certificate and just sign all node-certs with that CA cert without the need to cross-distribute node-certs.

Comment: Indeed, you probably have to create a new key pair and certificate for each node, but you should not have to trust each node separately, as long as one of the parent certificates is trusted. At least not for 99% of PKI solutions (I don't know Cassandra though).

Comment: Cassandra docs say that you need to add each node certificate to the truststore on every other node: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/security/secureSSLCertificates_t.html?scroll=task_ds_c14_xjy_2k

Comment: "Does Cassandra allow using a single certificate/key for all nodes in a cluster, or will it complain?": it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the CA cert to the truststore of each node is sufficient.